# Displaying unordered list keeps pushing to the right of div

Tags: html, css

I'm having difficulty aligning an unordered list inside a div.

As you can see by the picture, my list of icons are being pushed to the right instead of taking up 100% width of the div they are being contained in.

I'm pretty sure this is because I've set `list-style-type:none`

I'm not sure how to combat this without setting negative margins.

I'll also add the code used yet:

```css
div#mobile-nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 80px 0px 0px 0px;
}
ul.responsive {
  min-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul.responsive li {
  float: none;
}
ul.responsive li a {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 56px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
ul.topnav li {
  display: none;
}
ul.topnav li.icon {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobile-nav">
  <ul class="responsive">
    <li> <a href=""> HOME </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=""> ABOUT US </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=""> PROJECTS </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=""> CONTACT US </a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand why it is tough to use the `Tidy` button.

Comment: I meant the tidy button inside the Snippet! `:)` Okay, check out my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Reset the **default padding** of `<ul>`:

```css
div#mobile-nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 80px 0px 0px 0px;
}
ul.responsive {
  min-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;                       /* Here, reset like this! */
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul.responsive li {
  float: none;
}
ul.responsive li a {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 56px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
ul.topnav li {
  display: none;
}
ul.topnav li.icon {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobile-nav">
  <ul class="responsive">
    <li> <a href=""> HOME </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=""> ABOUT US </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=""> PROJECTS </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=""> CONTACT US </a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```